# How can I get the hostname where the service worker is installed?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Usually in javascript you can find the hostname using `window.location.hostname`, but it seems in service workers you cannot find the hostname using this method.

Is there any other elegant way to get the hostname dynamically?

Answer (score 22):

Code running in the context of a service worker can get the relevant hostname via `self.location.hostname`.

If you'd like to explore more of what's available inside of a service worker, the relevant documentation is for the [`ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope).

Specifically, you'll see that the `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope` inherits from [`WorkerGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope), and that, in turn, exposes a read-only [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/location) property.

Comment: I used this exactly on my web worker to open the hosted page and the self.location.hostname is also including the path to the service worker.
Any ideas around that?